# Увеличить время сессии

Tags: php

В массиве _SESSION есть два элемента, так вот можно ли увеличить время жизни для каждого элемента в отдельности (один должен жить долго, второй в зависимости от условия), и как это реализовать, не прибегая к изменениям в php.ini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как насчет передавать элементы в разных запросах?

Answer (score 0):

обернуть элементы в какой нибудь синглтон, рядом хранить время установки элементов, и по get-е элемента, проверять не устарел ли он. Ну естественно максимальное время жизни будет равно максимальному времени сессии.